# How to add a new column with non default delimiter using Azure Data Flows

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I have a text file with this format

A~B

E~F~G~H

K~L~P

How can I add a new string to every row like this

A~B~XXX

E~F~G~H~XXX

K~L~P~XXX

I am doing this so I will have XXX as the new column when I read the file later

I tried to add a new column using Derived Column, and the file looks like this

A~B,XXX

E~F~G~H,XXX

K~L~P,XXX

but later I can't read the file with two different delimiter (~ and , )

Comment: Can you provide what your expected result?

Comment: Hi @Rakesh, the expected out is a csv file with this format:

A~B~XXX  (Linebreak) 
E~F~G~H~XXX  (Linebreak) 
K~L~P~XXX  (Linebreak)

Comment: You want the above result in a single column or two columns? you mentioned you got it in two columns?

Comment: I want the above result in a csv file 1 column only. Hope it makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the above result in a csv file 1 column only.

Use the derived column for the same input column.

This is source data from text file.

[image]

Here, if we didn't provided any header, by default it will give the header as `Column_1`.
Use the same column in the derived column like below rather than creating new column.
To add the string use `concat(Column_1, '~XXX')` in it.

[image]

Result in csv file after dataflow execution using pipeline.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, it worked well. its much simpler than I thought. I missed this "Use the same column in the derived column like below rather than creating new column." I didn't know that I can use the same column name. Cheers !